# Calculus Question about Minimizing Cost with Area

Tags: calculus

Please Help

Completely stuck on this question

(i) A rectangular tennis court of 1800 square metres is to be fenced with 2 types of materials.
The shorter sides are made with fence material costing 100 Dollars per metre and the other sides with fence material costing 50 Dollars  per metre. Find the dimensions of the court to minimize cost.

I know I need a link, but are completely stuck on all else,

I only want hints as this is an important piece of work.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need a hint, let $p$ be price per meter.

$$ p_x=100,\, p_y= 50,\, A= 1800 $$

$$ p_x + p_y= P= 1800 $$

$$ x\, y = A $$

which are the object and constraint functions respectively.

This is a maxima/minima problem can be solved by differential calculus.

Eliminate second variable, differentiate w.r.t. first variable, solve first variable and plug into constraint to find second variable.

The method of Lagrange Multiplier gives a formula

$$ \frac{\partial P/\partial x}{\partial P/\partial y} =  \frac{\partial A/\partial x}{\partial A/\partial y} $$

Result is

$$ x_{opt}= \sqrt{A \, p_y / p_x } , \quad y_{opt}= \sqrt{A \, p_x / p_y}  $$

$$ = (60,30)$$

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Suppose the width is $x$, then the length is $\frac{1800}{x}$.

write down an expression describing the cost in terms of $x$, minimize it.

Answer (score 0):

You are seeking to minimize
$$50*2x+100*2y=100x+200y=f(x,y)$$
Subject to the constraint that 
$$
xy=1800
$$
Here $y$ is the length of the shorter side, and $x$ the length of the longer. Then solving our constraint for $y$ in terms of $x$ so we can minimize a single variable function we have
$$
y=\frac{1800}{x}
$$
Giving us a function 
$$
f(x)=100x+200*\frac{1800}{x}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Think So, I would have to find the derivative, and find the minimum, Right?

Comment: Yes, in order to mathematically verify the minimum you either plug in higher and lower values around the point, or you show that it has to be a minimum via 2nd derivative

Comment: My problem is now that the line when graphed is a linear line, so no minumum

Comment: it is not linear.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aiat2zugm5

Comment: Why did you add an $x$ in the second term. More importantly, why aren't you thinking before graphing? Does something of the form $x+1/x$ look linear?

Comment: @SomebodyNeedingHelp this calc is bullshit, because it shows way to high values on the axes. try graphing a few points with pen and paper, you'll see its not linear

Comment: Any ideas why the points wont give the area required ?

Comment: @SomebodyNeedingHelp Change to defaultzoom, zoom out and then zoom in where the graph begins. you HAVE TO change your formular to the correct one $100x + 360000/x$. But please look at this and the DEFINITION of linear. Please!

Comment: As i said, you typed in the equation incorrectly. Stop and think.

Comment: I get that it is not linear, but the minimum point is (60,12000), I'm pretty sure that doesn't give 1800 square metres

Comment: one side is 60. x*y=1800. Do you get it from here? 12000 is only the cost.

Comment: Thank you for the help, sorry for the dramas

Answer (score 0):

Solving this problem does not require any calculus.

If $x$ and $y$ are the two dimensions ($x$ the shorter), and $C$ is the total cost, then $$C=200x+100y$$ while $$xy=1800$$ Substituting:
$$C=200x+\frac{100\times 1800}{x}$$Multiplying through by $x$ and re-arranging:$$200x^2-Cx+180000=0 $$The discriminant of this quadratic, $D$, is given by $$D=C^2-4\times 200\times 180000$$For a real solution, $D$ must be non-negative, which implies that $$C = \sqrt{4\times 200\times 180000}=12000$$is the minimum value for $C$

Substituting this back into the quadratic leads directly to the value of $x$ and hence $y$